# On Linux get disk space used per user when you are not root

Tags: linux, storage, disk, du

`du --max-depth=1` will give the usage of the user you are logged in as. But we have a dev box shared by more than one team, so its getting tough to find the culprit.

If I am root I can do it but I am not the root user and dont want to ask the System Admins all the time  to find the user with most usage.

Any ideas on this please.

Comment: Isn't it the job of the sysadmin to enforce disk quotas, not regular users?

Comment: `du --max-depth=1 will give the usage of the user you are logged in as`

No it won't.

`but I am not the root user`

Then forget it - you don't have the access to check (if you were root you could do a recursive directory list and filter it through a simlpe awk script to tally up the number of files)

Comment: it was just a last resort to ask you guys. I was wondering if there is any hack I know that we cant read the files you dont have permission to. You thumbs down the question just for no reason and looks like you assume that I didnt do any research.. Dont just thumbs down H2CO3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't determine the size of directories you have no read/execute permissions for, so this is only possible when being root.